# Is ist possible to connect SLR or mirror-less cameras with Getac V110 directly (WLAN)?

Tags: mirrorless, camera-controls, slr, wireless, laptop

I'm working within a project where we do a lot of field mapping. To map objects we use the GPS-enabled,fully rugged convertible notebook Getac V110 (see [specs](https://www.getac.com/us/products/laptops/v110)). To create and edit objects we use a geographic information system (GIS) and an input form (Python coded).

At the moment we use an older SLR camera (Canon EOS 550D) to take a photo of every object mapped in the field. At office we have to compare the timestamps of the mapped object and the photo to assign the photo to the object.

In a next step we want to optimize this field work. I want to assign the unique ID of every new mapped object to the corresponding new photo I take in the field.

In detail:

1. I want to have a permanent, wireless connection between the notebook and the camera without using an extra WLAN Hot Spot like a Smartphone or Tablet.
2. I want to copy the last photo taken with the camera to my laptop
3. and to rename it with the use of my input mask (with Python code)

It is clear that this could be accomplished with a WLAN connection. I talked to the Canon Service and they told me it is possible with cameras like EOS 77D, 80D, 90D or M50. Some days before somebody from a photo shop told me that it is only possible with cameras like the Canon EOS M50 or the Panasonic DC - G9l and the EOS 77D would work only with an extra transmitter.

So I'm really unsure what kind of camera I can buy for this special task.

After creating a WLAN connection of notebook and camera is it possible to see the camera in the file system (Windows 7 64)? So that I can access the photos via Python?

Comment: Other than the ruggedized housing, is this anything different from an normal Windows laptop?

Comment: @mattdm, AFAIK this laptop have inside GPS unit which is something rare.

Comment: Right, but I don't see how that's relevant to the file-transfer question.

Comment: Would using the camera as the host for the WiFi connection between camera and the notebook? That may be the explanation for the disparity between whether certain WiFi enabled cameras are capable of what you want or not. The older Canon "consumer" models (like 77D, 80D) with WiFi can only host their own network, but not attach to a network hosted by another device/router. I'm not sure, but I think the newer ones can connect to another device's network. The WFTs used with the EOS 1-series have been able to do this for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to do tethering. One possible configuration is to use [DSLR Controller](http://dslrcontroller.com/) to add WiFi connection to your camera. Then on your computer you need to install [EOS Utility](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/software/eos-utility.html). Then you should make WiFi connection to router (DSLR Controller), start EOS Utility and start taking photos. Of course you can use Lightroom, CaptureOne or other software to take photos via tethering. The image files are stored in directory you specify. And from there your program can rename them. be aware Lightroom, CaptureOne can also rename photo to specific names after they are transferred to the computer.

BTW your camera is in to the [list of supported devices](http://dslrcontroller.com/devices.php) so you do not need new one.

And to clarify you need to buy and flash one router which will act as access point of your camera. Check on the [bottom of the devices page](http://dslrcontroller.com/devices.php)

Answer (score 0):

> After creating a WLAN connection of notebook and camera is it possible to see the camera in the file system (Windows 7 64)?

No. Canon cameras use proprietary protocols that require *EOS Utility* (free download) for communication between the camera and a computer, whether the connection is wireless or wired. Data exchange follows the PIMA 15740-2000 protocol, but with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does.

You can't treat the camera's memory card like an external drive. But *EOS Utility* does have the capability of automatically transferring images as they are taken. If your application is monitoring the folder on your local machine to which *EOS Utility* is writing the files, it should be able to detect each new file and then act on it.